# Flies in my apartment

Tags: pest-control, insect

I been seeing a lot of flies in my apartment this week. I been trying to figure out how they get in and if they have layed eggs somewhere. I only been having one window open and it have a screen but today I noticed that there a hole in the wood of that window. I'mean wounded if they come in through it and maybe laid eggs in it. What can I do about the flies?

Comment: It only takes one if there's a place for them to lay eggs. It's more likely that they follow you in when you use your door, though, depending on what "a lot" means.

Comment: soapy water kills them in seconds. Murphy Oil Soap seems to work fastest, but Dawn will kill them also.

Comment: I was having around 10 and then I kill them and more shows. I live in an apartment building so my door doesn't go outside so I'm sure they don't follow me.

Comment: Cleaned my place a little and filled the hole in the window frame and haven't seen any flies in a few days.